# why won't this string validation script work?

Tags: php, regex, oop

These functions are in a class file and they are being passed variables through a form.
Why will it say No match if I pass it a string with just the characters a-z or A-Z?

```
function pattern_check($patten, $string) {
$pass = preg_match($patten, $string);
return $pass;
}
function check_name($name) {
    $pat = '/^[a-zA-Z]/';
    $name = $this->pattern_check($pat, $name);
    if($name) {
        echo "Match";
    }
    else {
        echo 'No match';
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the string you are trying to check?

Comment: just a text input string with plain ASCII characters..

Comment: @Matthew, still the *exact* string would be handy just to clarify things.

Comment: @Aron Rotteveel it's just a a string $name = 'ABCDEFG';

Comment: Your code is perfectly valid and should match with that input. Try `var_dump $name` in before the `if ($name)` statement in `check_name`

Comment: You must tell how many chars the regexp should match
$pat = '/^[a-zA-Z]*/';

Comment: the result of var_dump is string(7)

Comment: Is there any error message/ Is error reporting on???

Comment: Matthew, which version of PHP are you running? ALso, turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL)`, are you getting the error `preg_match: internal pcre_fullinfo() error -3`?

Comment: I'm running php 5.3.5 and I turned E_ALL  on and I'm not getting any error messages..

Comment: FWIW this worked fine for me on 5.2 but [codepad threw an error](http://codepad.org/NKwvPoTV)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing you are currently trying to validate is, that the first char in your string is a letter. Nothing more, nothing less.

If you want to check the complete string for only being letters you will have to use a regex like `'#^[a-zA-Z]+$#'`. This ensures, that there are more than one letter is allowed. Also you will have to watch out with the encoding the tested string is of. If the string is utf8 you will have to use the `u` modifier with your regex like `#^[a-zA-Z]+#u`

Comment: Actually, the `'u'` modifier is required only when the _pattern_ contains unicode, not the target string.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work exactly as you have specified. It checks that a string *starts with* an alphabetic character. Your string must not be what you think it is.

I wrapped this in a test function and fed it some strings:

```
function test($name)
{
    echo "${name}: ";
    check_name($name);
    echo "\n";
}

test(" ZZ1");
test("123");
test("4aa");
test("AAA");
test("Z11");
test("ZZ ");
test("ZZZ");
test("aaa");
test("zzz");
test("Ábc");
```

Output...

```
% ./test.php    

 ZZ1: No match
123: No match
4aa: No match
AAA: Match
Z11: Match
ZZ : Match
ZZZ: Match
aaa: Match
zzz: Match
Ábc: No match

% php --version
PHP 5.3.4 (cli) (built: Dec 15 2010 12:15:07) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

The reuse of your `$name` variable may be confusing:

```
$name = $this->pattern_check($pat, $name);
if($name) {
```

Consider using this instead:

```
$matched = $this->pattern_check($pat, $name);
if ($matched) {
```

Answer (score 1):

If these functions are not a part of a php class .. then the error is in your line

```
$name = $this->pattern_check($pat, $name);
```

change it to

```
$name = pattern_check($pat, $name);
```

Let me know if it works?

UPDATE --
**Sorry** then .. as I just tested it quickly and it seemed to work

```
class mytest{


    private function pattern_check($patten, $string) {
        $pass = preg_match($patten, $string);
        return $pass;
    }
    public function check_name($name) {
        $pat = '/^[a-zA-Z]/';
        $name = $this->pattern_check($pat, $name);
        if($name) {
            echo "Match";
        }
        else {
            echo 'No match';
        }

    }

}
$obj = new mytest();
$obj->check_name('ABCDEFG');
OUTPUT -> Match
```

Comment: Reading the question I see `These functions are in a class file`, and then still he would not get a result, only errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have realized that the regular expression is incorrect, the correct pattern to check for a proper  name would be to make sure it's capitalized with lowercase letters after said capital so,

[A-Z]*[a-z]{1,50} would match true against any word starting with a capital and followed immediately after the capital with lowercase letters between 1 and 50 characters.